# automatically starting GUI program on startx

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xorg, x-windows

I have GUI code written in PyQt in `main.py` that I want to start up automatically after `startx` starts.

I've already configured my beaglebone (Debian) to run startx on power up.

I initially included the following in`/etc/x11/xinitrc:  @/usr/bin/python3 /root/PyQt/main.py`

This worked perfectly until I deleted some files from `/root` to create space on my beaglebone. I'm not sure what exactly I deleted (mostly log files) but I might have also deleted the `.XAuthority`, `.bash_profile`, `.config` folder, `.dbus` folder.

Ever since then, it hasn't been autostarting my `main.py` on boot. Even now, after new `.XAuthority`,`.bash_profile`, etc have been created, it still isn't auto-starting my program.

Is there a way to fix this? Or another way to autostart`main.py`?

Note: I'm running Debian on my beaglebone and lxqt.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line to `~/.xsession`:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /root/PyQt/main.py&
```

(note the final `&`) before the last line.

Or you can rely on your window manager to start it up for you.

Comment: I tried adding it to `xsession` already, and it doesn't work. How would i get the window manager to set it up for me?

Comment: It really depends on your window manager. Can you tell us which one are you using?

Answer (score -2):

step 1:  edit file `/etc/systemd/system/gogs_webhook.service`

#### file content

[Unit]

Description= your description (here  Service)
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=gogs
Group=gogs
WorkingDirectory=/root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/PyQt/main.py
                                                                                                                              Environment=USER=gogs HOME=/home/gogs
TimeoutStartSec=5
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

---

step 2：  `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

step 3： `sudo systemctl enable youselfservice.service`

setp 4 ： OK，then to reboot your PC or `sudo systemctl start youselfservice.service`

Comment: could you explain how/why this would work?